Stop express cross server from redirecting requests to another URL
I have a server that sends requests to a foreign server api.foreign.com/route. The problem is that when I send the requests from browser in the console I receive a cors allow-origin error and it says that the error is coming from www.foreign.com/route . The URL shouldn't change cause there is nothing on www.foreign.com/route. Here is the API on my server:
app.use('/api/fetchData', createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'https://api.foreign.com',
    changeOrigin: true,
    followRedirects: false,
    pathRewrite: (path, req) => {
        const { data } = req.query;

        return `/route?data=${data}`;
    },
    selfHandleResponse: true,
    on: {
        proxyRes: responseInterceptor(async (responseBuffer, proxyRes, req, res) => {
            try {
                console.log("requesting");
                if (!responseBuffer || typeof responseBuffer !== 'object' || responseBuffer.length === 0) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid or empty response from target server');
                }
                const response = responseBuffer.toString('utf8');

                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
            
                return JSON.stringify({ id: response });
            } catch (error) {
                res.statusCode = 500;
                return JSON.stringify({ error: 'Failed to process response from target server' });
            }
        }),
    },
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    }
}));

I tried doing the requests from Postman to api.foreign.com and I get a 200 response with the desired data. How do I prevent the url from changing.
I added the headers in the requests to prevent cors issues with the foreign server, but now they change the server url and this problem started to happen.

To solve the CORS error, the foreign server should allow your origin. Of course, when you test the api calling with Postman, you received 200 response but Postman does not run in the browser, so it doesn't enforce CORS policy, that's why you received 200 response in Postman. CORS policy is only implemented for domains so you can get data from the foreign server once they allowed your origin. Hope it helps you.

I understand. I had this problem before and as you can see in my implementation I used http-proxy-middleware and it solved the problem. Now it stopped working. Is there any way to solve it?
